# Battery power to DC mains power

Tags: voltage, batteries, dc, amperage, battery-operated

First time posting here :)
Hope someone can help.

I have a wireless Yale home alarm system and the external siren is chewing through batteries in no time and is expensive to keep replacing them.
I came to the conclusion that if I were to run it of a DC mains power adapter it would be hell of a lot cheaper to run.
The external siren uses 4 x D cell batteries (1.5v each) 
The batteries are in series so this is 6v.
With the batteries in series, I used a multimeter to check how much amps/current it is using when the siren is activated. 
It seems to be consuming about 450 ma when the siren is fully activated and consuming up to 220 ma in standby mode with just its warning LEDs flashing intermittently every 5 seconds.

I had a 6v DC 3500ma mains adapter lying about so thought this would be perfect to power it as it will only draw 450 out of the 3500 milliamps that the adapter supplies and should be sufficient enough.
I hardwired the adapter to the black and red terminals on the siren and made sure the polarity is correct.
When powered up, the siren seems to be getting some sort of power as it may make 1 beep or the leds might flash once on power up, but that is all. If I do a siren system test with the batteries inserted, it works perfectly with a continuous siren alarm and flashing LEDs.
If I do a siren system when connected to the DC power adapter, the LEDs don’t flash but the siren will only let out one burst of sound for like a second. Like one loud squelch and that’s it.
I’m totally confused why it won’t work on DC mains power when the voltage and the current output of the adapter seem to be similar to the battery power.
Any ideas or feedback are welcome folks!
Many thanks in advance :)

Please see YouTube link below to the Yale Siren I’m using:

https://youtu.be/CUIDHVbGK2o
 [image]

Comment: To the people voting to close: Perhaps it is benifficial to add a reason why you are voting to close. This way the OP can perhaps correct what you think is wrong with the question, instead of just seeing the question closed without any response.

Comment: Have you checked if voltage is 6V after connecting supply?

Comment: How confident are you in the measurements you made? Is it possible that the siring is taking a very high pulse load for very short timeperiods (far higher than what your supply can handle), resulting in the supply going into a protection mode or such?

Comment: [Reasons for closing: a question about consumer electronics](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: I understand it’s a consumer product, but I’m asking on grounds as I’m modifying it. Power reading of adapter is about 6.2v when connected and turned on. I presume the power pulses as it would rapidly increase when it activates and must fluctuate slightly with the flashing of the LED’s

Comment: @Jimmy you are not modifying the electronics - if you were folk here would expect some attempt at a schematic to be shown in your question. You have a consumer thing and you are having problems when you attach it to another consumer thing. Those things don't have schematics (that I can see) and people here are not magicians with endless time on their hands.

Comment: 220 ma in standby mode seems very excessive. It may be that there is a fault with the unit

Comment: @Jimmy The difference is dynamic resistance and a matching rechargeable battery(s) with float charger is best due to low ESR.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! This appears to be a reverse engineering, modification, or repair question. Please be aware that such questions must involve specific troubleshooting steps and demonstrate a good understanding of the underlying design of the device being discussed, so that you can ask specific, focused questions that can be answered concisely. More information can be found here: [Is asking how to fix a faulty circuit on topic?](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/q/2478/11683).

Comment: Oh my God somebody new who actually understands the ratings on a power supply

Comment: Jimmy - Welcome to SE.EE. I'm sorry you have had such a rough reception. Hang in there - it can be a useful place once you get past the pedants :-). | Your supply MAY be drooping under peak loads, but this doesn't seem too likely. | Some devices do not like excessively high Vin and SOME supplies have higher voltage when unloaded. From what you say this does not SEEM to be the case here. If it is an electronic switch mode converter (and not an iron core  transformer type) then Vout should be reasonably constant. | Adding a large as reasonably possible electrolytic capacitor across the psu ...

Comment: ... output / alarm input may help. 100 uF maybe useful. 1000 uF even more useful (but getting costlier. Cap voltage rating of >= 10V say. 6.3V probably OK if psu is REALLY always <= 6.2V but >= 10V better. | If that works then you MAY be able to use batteries and psu by adding a Schottky diode in series with both. Vdrop about 0.3 - 0.5V under load which MAY be too much. Cap above can go on alarm side of diodes. | If it works without diodes but Vdrop is too high with diodes you can use a relay to switch. Activate relay from PSU power and when activated switch psu to power alarm. ...

Comment: ... If power fails then battery operation starts. Repay changeover time MAY affect the alarm but maybe not. Large cap at alarm input helps but 200 mA drain is "rather large". | | As others say - the standby drain Iq sounds excessive -  if you remove alarm horn dies Iq drop substantially? - If so AC coupling with a cap will help.

Comment: The Yale 6200 manual says - "Power supply 6V, 4 x D alkaline
cells. 2 years typical service life." Standby current needs to be under 1 mA for this to be the case. "You have a problem." | Manual [**HERE**](https://data2.manualslib.com/pdf5/110/10914/1091372-yale/hsa6200.pdf?a5b12ffccff3e0127cfa61c74a18c103) see page 17. Or [**Downloadable PDF here](https://data2.manualslib.com/pdf5/110/10914/1091372-yale/hsa6200.pdf?a5b12ffccff3e0127cfa61c74a18c103&take=binary).

Comment: +1 - Good question. COULD be worded so as to better fit in site spec for questions. My above comments should help BUT the 200 mA if correct is FAR FAR too high.

Answer (score 1):

It could be that the initial surge of turning on the alarm is causing the voltage to drop too low.  Many electronics devices contain "brownout detector" logic that resets the system if the voltage drops below some threshold.  Alkaline cells have a pretty good pulse current capability, perhaps better than your external supply.

Energizer has [a good overview of battery internal resistance](http://data.energizer.com/pdfs/batteryir.pdf) on their website.  Internal resistance is measured by measuring the voltage change due to a step change in current a R = dV/dI, as shown below.

[image: Internal Resistance Measurment]

Energizer says that the typical internal resistance of a new cell is about 150 to 300 milliohms.  At 3.5A, the current rating of your supply, 4 new cells would drop the voltage only about 2V, assuming 0.15 ohms internal resistance.  That would still leave the voltage at the low end of the operable range for an alkaline cell.

You can try putting a large electrolytic capacitor in parallel with the battery terminals.  That could perhaps smooth out the initial surge and allow the external supply to work.

You could also take the device apart some more to determine what it is using for the siren and look up the peak current requirements, to see if they are within the capabilities of your supply.

If your meter has a min/max capability, you could try measuring the minimum voltage in the battery and external supply cases and see if the external supply is dropping lower when the siren turns on.

One final thought, 220ma in standby mode seems very high for any modern low power electronics device.  Perhaps the alarm is defective.